# Rotation-invariant measure on the circle & $\int z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I was exploring [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604055/invariant-measure-under-irrational-rotation-on-s1):
"Prove that the only Borel probability rotation-invariant measure on unit circle is normalized Lebesgue measure".

I have a question about [this remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1832889/1090274). I proved that if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $n\in\Bbb N_0$ then:
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb T}z^n d\lambda=\begin{cases}0, \ \ \text{if} \ n\not=0 \newline 1 \ \ \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

But I have two questions I didn't find answers to:

1. How to prove the  converse, that if $\lambda$ is a measure on $\Bbb T$ satisfying the above integral identities then $\lambda$ must be the Lebesgue measure? (I thought about denseness of polynomials in $L^2$, but it seems useless)
2. How this fact linked to the question about uniqueness of invariant measure?

I know that a measure $\mu$ is invariant under $T: X\rightarrow X$ iff
$$\int \limits_X f \ d\mu = \int\limits_X f\circ T \ d\mu\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall f\in L^1_\mu(X)$$
But I don't see how to apply this fact in our case.

Any hint is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "the converse", exactly?

Comment: @FShrike, it was stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604055/invariant-measure-under-irrational-rotation-on-s1/1832889#1832889) that if integrals of $z^n$ behave the way they do if measure is Lebesgue, then the measure is indeed Lebesgue

Comment: The conclusion holds for any regular Borel complex valued measure with bounded variation. If such measure is rotation invariant with respect to an angle $\alpha$ such that $\alpha/\pi$ is irrational, then it is a constant multiple of the Lebesgue measure. The Riesz representation theorem can be applied and the linear density of monomials $z^n$, $n\in\mathbb{Z},$ in $C(\mathbb{T}).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to question (1) in the OP, suppose $\mu$ is a (nonnegative) Borel measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}z^n\,\mu(dz)=\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}z^n\,\lambda(dz)$for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+=\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}$,  where $\lambda$ for a is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Then, by complex conjugation,
$$\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}p(z)\,\mu(dz)=\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}p(z)\,\lambda(dz)\tag{0}\label{zero}\end{align}$$
for any trigonometric polynomial function $p$ (i.e., for any $p\in\operatorname{span}(z^n:n\in\mathbb{Z})$
Clearly $\mu$ is finite: $\mu(\mathbb{S}^1)=1=\lambda(\mathbb{S}^1)$. Since trigonometric polynomials are dense in $(C(\mathbb{S}^1;\mathbb{C}),\|\;\|_u)$, \eqref{zero} extends to all $f\in C(\mathbb{S}^1;\mathbb{C})$.  The extension to all bounded Borel functions follows by monotone class theorem for functions:

> **Theorem** Suppose  $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^\Omega$ (resp. $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$) is  a real vector space containing the constant functions, and a monotone  (resp. a bounded monotone) class. If $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathcal{V}\cap\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$ is a multiplicative class, then  $\mathcal{V}$ contains all  real valued $\sigma(\mathcal{M})$--measurable functions.

For the  purposes of the OP, $\mathcal{V}$ is the space of all bounded Borel measurable functions $f$ that satisfy $\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}g\,d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}g\,d\lambda$, $\mathcal{M}$ is the collections of all real continuous functions on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Hence $\lambda=\mu$.

---

As for question 2, $\mathcal{S}^1$ with the complex product and the Euclidean topology is a topological compact Abelian group. The Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unique Haar measure (rotation invariant Borel measure) with $\lambda(\mathbb{S}^1)=1$. Any other Haar measure is a constant multiple of $\lambda$.