# Unique measure on positive Borel sets with following properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is actually part (a) question asked previously. However, that person had solved part (a) and so no solution is available. I am trying to prove it myself but am running in to difficulties.

$\textbf{Question}$ 
(a) Show that there is at most one measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{B}_{(0,\infty)}$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $\nu((1,e]) = 1$
2. $\nu(cA) = \nu(A)$ for every $c>0$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}_{(0,\infty)}$.

I think that somehow $(1,e]$ will generate all of the sets in $B_{(0, \infty)}$ but I am having a hard time formalizing the proof.

Comment: Do you know about uniqueness of Haar measure? Also, you could try to "transplant" the measure $\mu$ to the whole real line using logarithm/exponential function. This will give you a familiar looking question on the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [@PhoemueX](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/151552/phoemuex)'s comment,
one way to go about doing this proof is to use the two following facts:

**Fact 1.** Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be measures on $\mathcal B_{(0,\infty)}$ and $T:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be measurable and bijective (with respect to $\mathcal B_\mathbb R$).
Then, $\mu=\nu$ if and only if $\mu\circ T^{-1}=\nu\circ T^{-1}$.

**Fact 2.** The Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is the only measure on $\mathcal B_\mathbb R$ such that $\lambda\big((0,1]\big)=1$ and $\lambda(c+A)=\lambda(A)$ for every Borel set $A$ and $c\in\mathbb R$.

Fact 1 is fairly easy to prove.
Fact 2 is one of the most fundamental property of the Lebesgue measure.
Its demonstration can easily be found in most measure theory textbooks or online (see for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147089/translation-invariant-measures-on-mathbb-r) math.stackexchange question).

Suppose we define the map $T$ as $T(x)=\ln(x)$ for every $x\in(0,\infty)$ (and thus,
$T^{-1}(y)=e^y$ for all $y\in\mathbb R$).
Clearly,
this is bijective and measurable (since it is continuous).

At this point, it shouldn't be too hard to show that if $\nu$ satisfies conditions 1. and 2. in the statement of your question,
then $\mu=\nu\circ T^{-1}$ is such that $\mu\big((0,1]\big)=1$ and that $\mu(c+A)=\mu(A)$ for all $A$ Borel. Then use facts 1 and 2.

---

Also mentioned by [@PhoemueX](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/151552/phoemuex),
this is a special case of the uniqueness of the [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure):

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group equipped with a topology making the operations of group product and inverse continuous (for example, the set $(0,\infty)$ with the usual multiplication is a group, and we can equip this group with the standard Euclidean topology, making it locally compact, and the multiplication and inverse are continuous). Let $\mathscr B(G)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $G$. A measure $\mu$ on $\mathscr B(G)$ is said to be a left Haar measure if $\mu(cA)=\mu(A)$ for every $c\in G$ and $A\in\mathscr B(G)$.

The general proof of the existence and uniqueness of the Haar measure is quite sophisticated,
but the proof for $\mathbb R$ equipped with the usual addition (which yields the Lebesgue measure) is much easier and was known for a very long time.
In this context,
it is interesting to note that the map $T(x)=\ln(x)$ is actually both a group homomorphism and a homeomorphism between $\big((0,\infty),\cdot\big)$ and $(\mathbb R,+)$.