# Proving the existence of a real number in a finite measure of a translation invariant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, multiplicative-function

Someone please explain this:
Presume that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, that $x + A = \big\{ x + a \mid a \in A \big\}$. Here, *A* and *x + A* are Borel sets for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, if $\mu$ is a *σ*-finite measure on *B* (so that *λ*($\mathbb{R}$) = *∞*) and *λ* is a translation invariant, how can it be shown that  there exists a real number *c* > 0 such that $\mu$ = *c λ*? I know that $\mu$(A) = *c λ(A)* for all Borel sets A. I also know that the Lebesgue
measure is the unique translation invariant measure on *B*, up to a multiplicative constant.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147089/translation-invariant-measures-on-mathbb-r

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: What is actually your question? If $\mu$ is an arbitrary measure, then your statement is wrong, consider for example $\mu=0$. I thought you maybe ask: If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite on the Borle set $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and translation invariant, does then a constant $c > 0$ exist with $\mu = c \lambda$. But this is exactly the answer of the link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: I just noticed that you wrote: **I know that $\mu(A)=c \lambda(A)$ for all Borel-sets**. But this is the definition of $\mu = c \lambda$. What are you asking for?